# Lightbox not opening on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I made my own lightbox javascript and css but somehow it wont work on iPhones.

Why is that?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
//lightbox open
jQuery('.lightbox_trigger').css('cursor','pointer');
jQuery('.lightbox_trigger').live('click', function(){
jQuery('#overlay, #lightbox').show();
});
});

<a href="#" class="lightbox_trigger qbutton or-border-btn" onClick="">TICKETS</a>
```

as you can see I tried multiple things already like adding cursor: pointer and an empty onClick.
Still wont work for iPhones. Am I missing something?

Comment: Indent your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.lightbox_trigger').live('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
```

I think the iPhone try to go to # from the `href` so if you put a `preventDefault` you don't have this behavior.